# Overwriting module value dynamically with RequireJs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am trying to create an interface, with same methods, that do same things depending on the device where my web app is running. I would like to create a module empty, and depending on the device, owerwrite that value (I don´t want to load any module that is not neccessary). Currently, I have 3 modules.

First one, once everything is loaded execute the method init from module main:

```
require( [ "browser", "valueDynamic" ], function( browser, valueDynamic ) {

    switch ( browser ) {

        case "android":
            require( [ "android", "main" ], function( android, main ) {
                valueDynamic = android;
                main.init();
            } );
            break;

        case "pc":
            require( [ "pc", "main" ], function( pc, main ) {
                valueDynamic = pc;
                main.init();
            } );
            break;

    }


} );
```

Module valueDynamic, just and empty object that I will overwrite in time execution in previous module:

```
define(function() {

    return {};

} );
```

And finally module main, with init method:

```
define( [ "valueDynamic" ],

    function( valueDynamic ) {
        var main = {};

        main.init = function() {
            console.log(valueDynamic); // Object empty
        };

        return main;
    }
);
```

Why valueDinamyc is empty? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot, best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using JavaScript incorrectly. The behavior you're seeing is exactly the same as if you ran this pure JavaScript code:

```
var value = {
    // This field is there to distinguish the object from an
    // completely empty one. The same demonstration would work if
    // value was set to {}.
    distinctive: 1
};

function foo(bar) {
    console.log("value before", value);
    console.log("bar before", bar);
    bar = "something";
    console.log("bar after", bar);
    console.log("value after", value);
}

foo(value);
```

When `foo(value)` is called, `bar` is set to refer to the same object as `value`. The line `bar = "something"` overwrites `bar` so that instead of being a reference to an object, it is a string.

The same thing happens with your `valueDynamic` module. What you could do is have a field of `valueDynamic` hold the platform value:

```
define(function() {

    return { platform: undefined };

} );
```

And then in your platform detection you do:

```
valueDynamic.platform = android;
```

And your do this to dump it to the console:

```
console.log(valueDynamic.platform);
```

Comment: Instead of: `bar = "something";` would not it be `value = "something"?`. I want to atach all the method to the object `valueDynamic`. `android` or `pc` are objects with methods, I want to copy all the method to valueDynamic. I havee seen that I can iterate for example, android object, and copy one by one each method to `valueDynamic`. I am not sure if it is an elegant solution. Thanks @Louis!

Comment: My example is a correct representation of what is going on in your code. When you assign to `valueDynamic` in the code you show in the question you are modifying *the argument passed to the callback you give to `require`*. You are not modifying *the module*.

Comment: Is it possible modify the module? I was thinking in defining my module like this:

`define(function() {

    var valueDynamic = {};

    valueDynamic.set = function( moduleToCopy ){
        
        for (var prop in moduleToCopy) {
            if (moduleToCopy.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                valueDynamic[prop] = moduleToCopy[prop];
            }
        }

    };

    return valueDynamic;

} );`

And instead of `valueDynamic = android;` it would be `valueDynamic.set(android);`

Comment: Code in a comment is hard to read but it looks like it should work. I was suggesting that you set a single `platform` field on `valueDynamic` which would then be a reference to the object describing the platform. What I see in your comment is instead taking the object which describes the platform and copying all its fields onto `valueDynamic`. If setting one field on `valueDynamic` works, then setting many fields also works.

Comment: Yes that is what it does. I don´t want to have `valueDynamic.android.nameMethod` and then `valueDynamic.pc.nameMethod`. I want that independently from the platform, the method invocation is always the same `valueDynamic.nameMethod`. I know better RequireJS now. Thanks for your comments.